# Replace characters with padding zeros

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with values:

```
100-1234-5
100-0004567-00
300-122334556-87
```

and I need to replace the first dash (-) with zeros, so that the total length is exactly 18 characters, and insert it back into the database:

```
1000000000000123-45
1000000000004567-00
3000000122334556-87
```

If that is not possible, then maybe do the same using grep

Comment: And why does the second dash move?

Comment: Your expected results have length = 19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to replace the first dash (-) with zeros, so that the total length is exactly 18

You can deconstruct the string and then put it back together:

```
select (regexp_substr(str, '[^-]+', 1, 1) || 
        rpad('0', 19 - length(str), '0') ||
        regexp_substr(str, '[^-]+', 1, 2) || '-' ||
        regexp_substr(str, '[^-]+', 1, 3)
       )
from t;
```

Note that this returns the results that you *describe*, not the results given in the question -- I assume you have a typo there.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=58abb33d863aad5b6022037e7b19e170) is a db<>fiddle

This is easily incorporated into an `update`:

```
update t
    set str = (regexp_substr(str, '[^-]+', 1, 1) || 
               rpad('0', 19 - length(str), '0') ||
               regexp_substr(str, '[^-]+', 1, 2) || '-' ||
               regexp_substr(str, '[^-]+', 1, 3)
              );
```

Comment: brilliant! Works like a charm. Also thanks for noticing the typo - I actually need total length of 19, but it is easy to change in your example

Answer (score 0):

Try below if it helps

```
     Select 

        RPAD(
         SUBSTR(INSTR(String, '- 
            '),INSTR(String, '-')), '0'
        18-Length(String)) 


    FROM TABLE
```